# Testcafe - How to assert two different location.pathname

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using testcafe and I have two platforms (Live and UAT). I would like to include both pathnames into my assertion and I have tried to use the below but it is not working. Any idea?

```
//Live pathname = /next
//UAT pathname = /

Code:

import { Selector, ClientFunction} from 'testcafe';
import { essUser, companyUser } from '../roles';
const getWindowLocation = ClientFunction(() => window.location.pathname.toString());

fixture('Validate login');
test('can successfully login as a user', async t => {
    await t.useRole(essUser);

    const location = await getWindowLocation();

    await t.expect(location).match(/\/next||\//);
});



// I am trying to use the OR but even though I am changing the /next to /neee, it is still passing which is not correct.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp is wrong, it should be:

```
await t.expect(location).match(/(\/next|\/)$/);
```

You use `()` for a group and `|` for logical OR.

**EDIT:** The regexp now matches the patterns only at the end of the string/url, which was made clear in the comment section.

Comment: Thank you for the above correction.

However, when I run run the code with the Live URL, it still passes when I was expecting it to fail due to the incorrect string (Nerr)

Comment: This regexp `.match(/(\/next|\/)/)` means: "match '/next' or '/'". I guess you still have "/" in the url. That's why it passes.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I am thinking too. I have been struggling to find a way since yesterday and I am fairly new to testing let alone Testcafe :-D

Comment: So what's the trouble then? You don't want it to pass when there's no "/next" in the URL? Why don't just leave out that OR and group part from the regexp then? Like so: `.match(/\/next/)`

Comment: If I put it like .match(/\/next/), it will assert correctly. 
You see, I have two environments and the same test will run for both environments which have different URL ofcourse and thus different pathname. 

As the same test is running for both environments, i wanted to add the logical OR.

I hope it does make sense.

Comment: You can change the regexp a bit so it matches the pattern only at the end of the url: `.match(/(\/next|\/)$/)`. Then if your url end with `/neee`, it won't pass.

Comment: It worked!!!!!!
Thank you so much @Pavelsaman. Its the first time I have posted on this forum and I am really really happy. For a beginner like me, I am really grateful for your time and guidance.